# Shadow not fully extending the width of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm applying a background shadow on a UIView to give it the appearance of it being "on top of" the background (which is a MapView), however the shadow doesn't fully extend on the wider iPhone 6 and 6+ screens even though the UIView I'm applying it to does.

In `viewDidLoad` I am applying the shadow to the UIView using this code:

```
CALayer *layer = self.view_detailview.layer;
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80f;
layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds] CGPath];
```

In my storyboard I have a constraint set to force the UIView width to match the superviews width which is working without any problems or warnings.  But when I run my the app on a 6 or 6+ I see that the shadow doesn't fully extend like so:

[image: Screenshot of how shadow doesn't extend]

I can verify that the UIView does use the full width by setting its background color to something noticeable and seeing it fill the screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the bounds value when the view hasn't been properly layout yet.

Set the shadow in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (if using a view controller) or in `layoutSubviews` (if using a standalone view). In the second case, don't forget to call `[super layoutSubviews]`.

Or don't change the `shadowPath` at all. Doesn't it work without that line?

Comment: Yep!  That did the trick.  I moved it from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it works perfectly.  It does work without the `shadowPath` line, but it seems to take a performance hit without it.